# Make a multiple panel structure to insert graphs of different sizes afterwards (16 in total)

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel, par

I made 15 pie charts, and one line chart.

My goal is now to line them up according to the structure on the picture

[image]

Is there a way like

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

to build such a structure, in which I can afterwards plot all the graphs I made? Accept that in this case, I would like to be able to determine the sizes of the plots.

Comment: Usually people end up using the `gridExtra` package for complicated layouts. `grid.arrange` may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
l <- cbind(c(5:1, NA), rbind(6:10, matrix(16, 5, 5)), c(11:15, NA))

# dummy placeholders for illustration
plots <- lapply(1:16, function(ii) 
            grobTree(rectGrob(), textGrob(paste("plot", ii))))

grid.arrange(grobs=plots, layout_matrix=l)
```

[image]

for actual plots, try

```
 plots <- replicate(16, ggplot(), simplify = FALSE)
```

or a list of your 16 plots (or grid grobs),

[image]

Comment: My apologies for the basic question, but I am not used to working a lot with grobTree: if I want to paste graphs (for instance l1, l2, l3... till l16) in  this structure, how do I do that? Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: place the grobs in a `list()` and pass it as `grobs=` in `grid.arrange()`, or just pass them one by one as unnamed arguments and `...` will take care of it.

Comment: Hey baptiste! I ended up using your code. Thank you very much for that! However, I have 2 additional questions: 1) is there a way to make the smaller plots larger, without changing the size of the larger plot? 2) Is there a way to have less white spaces in between the graphs?

In any case: thank you very much!

Comment: 1) it's not clear how to keep the same layout as you initially proposed and change the size of the smaller plots (how/where will they fit around the big one?); 2) The white space is typically controlled by the plot margin of each individual plot, which can be controlled in the theme settings for ggplot. Ask a new question if you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the first comment Baptiste. I didn't think about that. I do believe that the margins could be a solution, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I asked a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742779/change-a-multiple-panel-structure-16-graphs-to-make-certain-graphs-bigger) but before I leave here: once again thank you very much for your help! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to extract the dimensions to some type of matrix, but this verbose way will get you there and allow you to see what's going on in terms of size and placement - pretty sure it's a wrapper to `grid` or `gridExtra`:

```
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(p1, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.6, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1) +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.1, 0, 0.6, 0.5) # this is the big one
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice answer. One of the graphs I have is not made with ggplot. Is it true that in that case I cannot use the package you proposed? Or is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Depending on the exact nature of the `ggplot` plot, you may be better off with `library(grid)` and `library(gridExtra)` -- [see this](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Mixing-ggplot2-graphs-with-other-graphical-output) for more detail. You may also want to consider the [`ggfortify` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @JasonAizkalns! I ended up using Baptiste his suggestion, but I keep in mind your code when I have ggplots that I want to arrange differently!